# How to retrieve MS Access system information

Tags: ms-access

Does anyone know how to get the list of databases in MS Access? Is there any kind of table where system information is stored?

Comment: Do you mean a list of tables or a list of databases?

Answer (score 1):

No. Each database is an .mdb (or eventually othe rmore recent extensions) file on the file system.

Comment: `C:\>Dir *.mdb /s/p` or *.mde, *.accdb, *.accde  :)